# Combo box in vb6 firing on click before i select any item

Tags: list, vb6, combobox, click

I have a vb6 application which has a combo box on it, on this combo box _click event i have written some code but noticed that this event is firing even when i open the list of items in combo box, i have other combo boxes in my application as well they all fire _click when an item is select from list not when the list is opening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 type of combo box in vb6, choose the right style for a combo to get the beahviour you want in property window of a combo box, Source:

http://visual-basic.itags.org/visual-basic/82371/

Comment: While this is correct, I can't replicate the behavior you describe (the `Click` event being raised when you open the list, rather than when selecting an item) with *any* of the three options that are available. One style doesn't even have a drop-down box, and the other two only raise the `Click` event when an item in the list is clicked. The link that you posted only describes differences between the `Change` event, not the `Click` event.

Comment: @Cody Gray, i for sure had this behavuiour of combo box opening on click changing its type from Dropdown list to Dropdown Combo Box solved this problem, i am using vb6 sp5 with some cutom controls like vslight.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly meant to handle the `Change` event, not the `Click` event.

Comment: i know change event means also the same but the click event fires after an item in dropdown box in vb6

Comment: i am using custom contorl like vslight, for which .ocx libraries are needed. dont know if there anything involved in that